# I have a csv create script working on my local host but when uploaded to my web server the page doesnt load

Tags: php, csv, localhost, html, bluehost

Basically I have the following code in my folder. So I have my signup.php which is like my index.php(main page) and I have my cvs_func.php that holds the functions for creating the cvs file. It all works fine on my localhost but when I upload it to my webserver(BlueHost) nothing appears on the page.

Here is my signup.php

```
<?php
//session_start();
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/csv_func.php');

//give file path of csv file below
$data = read_csv('test.csv');

$data[] = array('5','Gareth','Bale','7/27/14');

write_csv('test_2.csv', $data);

//display add page
if(isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $show_modal = false;

    if(empty($fname) or empty($lname))
    {
        $error = true;
    }else
    {
        $thank_you = true;

        $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO signin_form (cust_fname, cust_lname, cust_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

        $query->bindValue(1, $fname);
        $query->bindValue(2, $lname);
        $query->bindValue(3, time());

        $query->execute();
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alva Sign In</title>
        <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php 
                date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
            ?>
            <a href="admin" class="admin">Admin</a><br/>

            <h1>Welcome to Alva Dynamics!</h1>
            <h2>Please sign in below.</h2>

            <form action="signup.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                <center><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"></center>
                <center><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"></center>
                <center><input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn" /></center>
            </form>

            <?php 
                if(isset($error))
                { 
                    echo "<h3>Please enter your first and last name!</h3>";
                } 
            ?>
            <?php 
                if(isset($thank_you))
                { 
                    echo '<h3 class="ty">Thank you for signing in!</h3>';
                } 
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my csv_func.php

```
<?php

//reads a csv file returning an array of rows
function read_csv($filename)
{
    $rows = array();

    foreach(file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line)
    {
        $rows[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    return $rows;

}
//writes the given array of rows to a csv file
function write_csv($filename, $rows)
{
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($file, $row);
    }

    fclose($file);

}
?>
```

So it wont display anything on the webpage but I should still see a form to input a first and last name. But when I load the code I get a blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Might be a permissions issue. Also add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Could be anything.

Comment: @Fred -ii- So I added the error reporting and am now getting the following error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_getcsv()` but I know BlueHost is running the 5.4 version of PHP so this function should work. Any ideas?